# Getting the same value again and again using Rnd

Tags: vba

Start:

```
Randomize()
        'randomValue = CInt(Math.Floor((upperbound - lowerbound + 1) * Rnd())) + lowerbound
        Dim value As Integer = CInt(Int((2 * Rnd()) + 1))
        intNumber = value - 1
            Dim y As Integer
        For y = 0 To 1
            ' Check arrNumber (y)
            'If intnumber has already been selected,
            'Then go and select another one.
            If intNumber = arrNumber(y) Then
                GoTo Start
            End If
        Next y
```

im am getting same value of value variable again

Comment: RFC 1149.5 specifies 4 as the standard IEEE-vetted random number

Comment: Is this VBA or VB.Net?

Comment: Could you submit the complete function please.

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to achieve with this function? Are you trying to an array with either a zero or one? Since you don't seem to assign a value to `arrNumber(y)`, it will default to zero and the thing will keep looping... I recommend that you state your problem more clearly - the solution will then be more obvious. Perhaps showing enough code that we can reproduce your problem would help; but stating what you want to achieve is even more important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have posted an incomplete and non-working code sample, it's difficult to tell where your problem is.

I reduced your code to the core:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Randomize()

    Dim value As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To 100
        value = CInt(Int((2 * Rnd()) + 1))
        Debug.Print value
    Next i
End Sub
```

This code randomly prints the values 1 and 2 to the Immediate window (press CTRL-G to open it). The small range [1, 2] is due to the scaling with the value 2. It could easily be increased.

So `Rnd()` seems to just work fine.